# Are all data types strings in Neo4j accessed by py2neo through the REST API?

Tags: python, nosql, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have a query of this form creating a new node in neo4j:

`cypher.get_or_create_indexed_node(index="person", key="name", value="Fred", properties={"level" : 1}`

However, when I query Fred to inspect his properties, his level = "1" /with quotes/.  It appears something is converting his value to a string.  This wouldn't matter much---I could convert it on retrieval if necessary---except when I try to do cypher queries like...

`start b = node:person("*:*") RETURN b.level, ID(b) ORDER BY b.level desc SKIP 5 LIMIT 5;`

...I notice that b.level is not being ordered as expected.  I'm seeing something like:

```
==> +-------------------------+
==> | b.level         | ID(b) |
==> +-------------------------+
==> | "3"             | 42    |
==> | "0"             | 53    |
==> | "2"             | 57    |
==> | "0"             | 63    |
==> | "2"             | 20    |
==> +-------------------------+
```

when I expect something like:

```
==> +-------------------------+
==> | b.level         | ID(b) |
==> +-------------------------+
==> | 3               | 42    |
==> | 2               | 20    |
==> | 2               | 57    |
==> | 0               | 63    |
==> | 0               | 53    |
==> +-------------------------+
```

I assume this is a data-type issue, since the [reference manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-skip.html) shows skip/limit functionality.

Is it the case that all values are strings, or that there's something else I should add to input correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not be the case, numeric properties are fully supported. I am also not able to recreate the scenario using the following test:

```
def test_get_or_create_indexed_node_with_int_property(self):
    graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
    fred = graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node(index="person", key="name", value="Fred", properties={"level" : 1})
    assert isinstance(fred, neo4j.Node)
    assert fred["level"] == 1
    graph_db.delete(fred)
```

I notice that you have prefixed the `get_or_create_indexed_node` method with `cypher` - I would not expect this since the cypher module does not have such a method. I would instead expect it to be either something like `graph_db` or `batch`. Maybe this is a typo?

Maybe you could share some more of your surrounding code? Something else around it may be affecting your results.

Nige

Comment: I'm a dummy, I had actually created this example as a minified version of what was causing the problem.  This works fine, the original didn't because I had somewhere defined my input as a string, rather than an integer.  I don't know SO practices on this, but that definitely answers my title question.  If I'm still having problems with the sort function after I refactor that, I may split that into a second question.

Comment: Yeah, that's the right answer and both problems are solved.  I misdiagnosed my problem with skip and limit.  Fixing the types did fix that, too, and also good to know types work correctly.  Thanks!